# Reading a ply file in matlab (output from Noah Snavely's tool Bundler)

Tags: matlab, 3d, visualization, mesh

I'm trying to open .ply files and display them in matlab using the following code :

http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/ply_display/ply_display.m

But it is showing an error

```
XY_DISPLAY:
Enter the name of the point file (in 'quotes'!).
'C:\SFM\examples\ET\bundle\points001.ply';
27    verbose = 0;
Error using ply_display>ply_to_tri_surface (line 140)
No such file or directory

Error in ply_display (line 48)
[ node_xyz, element_node ] = ply_to_tri_surface ( ply_filename );

Error in ply_display>ply_to_tri_surface (line 732)
ply_display ( 'C:\SFM\examples\new one\bundle\points001.ply' );

Error in ply_display (line 48)
[ node_xyz, element_node ] = ply_to_tri_surface ( ply_filename );
```

Can anyone please help me regarding this ?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling the function and what error do you receive?  There is no obvious reason why that particular line would cause an error.

Comment: You might try to contact the author at fsu: https://www.sc.fsu.edu/people?q=Burkardt&t=sn

Comment: Why are there two different paths names in the error message? (`'C:\SFM\examples\ET\bundle\points001.ply'` and `'C:\SFM\examples\new one\bundle\points001.ply'`)

Comment: Oh actually I was trying it with different examples. That's why!

Answer (score 0):

As should be pretty clear from the error output, your error is not in line 27 (actually I don't know why that shows up).  What the error trace shows you is this:

1) The error starts when `ply_display` calls another function, `ply_to_tri_surface` (which is defined in the same file).

> [ node_xyz, element_node ] = ply_to_tri_surface ( ply_filename );

2) Within that second function, the actual error is being triggered at line 140:

> ```
> Error using ply_display>ply_to_tri_surface (line 140)
> No such file or directory
> ```

(The reference to line 732 is a bit of a red herring - that is because this is where the error is being returned from `ply_to_tri_surface` to `ply_display` I think).

Looking at the actual code, this is the part causing the error (around line 140) - where the program first tries to open your file:

```
  [ fid, Msg ] = fopen ( ply_filename, 'rt' );

  if ( fid == -1 )
    error ( Msg );
  end
```

That is, `ply_filename` - your ply file - cannot be found.  Either the filename is wrong or the way you are inputting it (are you typing that semicolon at the end of the filename?) is causing issues.

Two options:

1) Run `dbstop if error`, then re-run the code. When it errors, you should be able to see what `ply_filename` contains.  (Run `dbquit` to exit debug mode).

2) Input your filename directly when running by calling the function from the command line, e.g. `ply_display('test.ply')` or `ply_display(filename)` where filename is a previously defined variable.

Comment: Thanks! But now I'm getting this : Warning: Unable to interpret TeX string "C:\SFM\examples\alsdorf\bundle\points030.ply" .                 How to solve this ? @nkjt